# .NET MAUI: How to get the postion of the context menu

Tags: c#, maui

I want to open a context menu (or something similar) and pass the coordinates of the tap to the commands/clicked events it contains.

Either from having a position and opening a context menu there or opening a context menu and getting the position of the context menu right click. I am fine with both.

I tried to open a context menu manually after receiving a right click event at a specific location but I could not figure out (or look up) how to make a context menu in the code-behind and I also don't know how to trigger it.

My .xaml:

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout
        Grid.Row="0"
        Background="Red"
        x:Name="AbsLayoutContainer" >
    <Image
            x:Name="BackgroundImage"
            Source="blueprint1.jpg"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0, 1, 1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" />

    <AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="OnLayoutRightClick"
                    Buttons="Secondary" />
    </AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

My code-behind:

```cs
public void OnLayoutRightClick(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    Point? pointInAbsLayoutContainer = e.GetPosition((View)sender);
    DisplayContextMenu(pointInAbsLayoutContainer);
}

void DisplayContextMenu(Point? tapLocation)
{
    if (tapLocation == null)
        return;

    var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
    // Dont know how to continue here
}
```

As you can see I already have a position in this approach but I don't know how to open a context menu from there.

I would like a simple context menu like this that may be expanded in the future:

```xml
<FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem
                Text="Notiz hinzufügen"
                Clicked="OnAddNoteClicked" />
        </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
```

I am fine with everything as long I have some kind of nice menu and can use the position of the click/tap.

Comment: Have you checked the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap#get-the-gesture-position)?

Comment: @Julian Yes I already used the link you provided. The problem is creating a context menu and starting it from there so I keep the location

Comment: Please update your question to make that more clear, because the title and parts of the description suggest that you don't know how to get the position. You don't know how to place the context menu in that position that you've successfully obtained already?

Comment: @Julian I am asking for a general way to get a context menu and a position. Either from having a position and opening a context menu there or opening a context menu and getting the position of the context menu right click. I am fine with both

Comment: Yes, I got that now. General recommendations are usually off-topic on Stack Overflow. You need to describe a specific problem that can be properly answered. Do you already have some code for the context menu, like a layout that you would like to display? Do you actually want to use the Desktop [MenuFlyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu) as indicated in your code sample? That's usually linked to specific controls and I'm not sure if you can actually set the location yourself.

Comment: @Julian I added a simple context menu I would like to use. If there is a better method than MenuFlyout I would love to know but I am afraid my problem will not remain specific enough then for SO.

Comment: One approach that works is capturing the last right-click-location in a method and saving it as a member so you can access it in the clicked-method of you context menu. This approach works but it is not pretty at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given your premises here is a suggestion or at least something you can use as a starting point. I have added some features you didnt mentioned, just for the completeness of it all.

We want a context menu to show up on an AbsolutLayout. So let us start with some basic code and some buttons. We do this in a StackLayout and put an border around it. Also we want the BackgroundColor to change when we hover over each button. Then we want a command to trigger once we click on a button.

```cs
public class CustomContextMenu : StackLayout
{
    private StackLayout _layout;
    private Border _border;

    public CustomContextMenu()
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
        _layout = new StackLayout();

        AddButton("Option 1", Colors.LightGray);
        AddButton("Option 2", Colors.Blue);
        AddButton("Option 3", Colors.Red, () => Hide());

        _border = new Border
        {
            Content = _layout,
            Stroke = Colors.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Margin = -2,
            Padding = 5,
            ZIndex = 10,
            StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle()
            {
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5)
            }
        };

        Children.Add(_border);

        this.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void AddButton(string text, Color hoverColor, Action action = null)
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
            TextColor = Colors.Black,
            HeightRequest = 5,
            BorderWidth = 0,
            Text = text,
            Command = action != null ? new Command(action) : null
        };

        PointerGestureRecognizer pointerGestureRecognizer = new PointerGestureRecognizer();
        pointerGestureRecognizer.PointerEntered += (s, e) =>
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = hoverColor;
        };
        pointerGestureRecognizer.PointerExited += (s, e) =>
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        };

        button.GestureRecognizers.Add(pointerGestureRecognizer);

        _layout.Children.Add(button);
    }

    public void ShowAt(double x, double y)
    {
        if (IsVisible) return;

        this.TranslationX = x;
        this.TranslationY = y;
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        this.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

We have an AbsoluteLayout. So the code behind can looks like this. Added bonus is that it hides the menu if we click outside it.

```cs
private CustomContextMenu contextMenu = new CustomContextMenu();

public MainPage(NotificationCounter notificationCounter)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AbsLayoutContainer.Children.Add(contextMenu);

    var tapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapGesture.Tapped += (s, e) =>
    {
        contextMenu.Hide();
    };

    AbsLayoutContainer.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
}

private void OnLayoutRightClick(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = (Point)e.GetPosition(this);
    contextMenu.ShowAt(point.X, point.Y);
}
```